# Does autowiring the constructor cause Spring to create at least one instance of that object?

Tags: java, spring, constructor, autowired

I an looking at code that assigns an object to a static reference via autowiring of the constructor:

```
@Component
class MySpringClass {
  private static PaymentRepo paymentRepo;

  @Autowired
  MySpringClass(PaymentRepo repo) { MySpringClass.paymentRepo = repo; }

  static void usePaymentRepoToDoStuff() { …. using paymentRepo ….. }
}
```

I've read that assigning static references via autowiring is not recommended. I didn't do it. Not my code.

I can't find a place where even one instance of MySpringClass is explicitly created (but this is a lot of code). This code works reliably.

So, does **@Autowired** cause Spring to create at least one instance of **MySpringClass**, and thus the constructor to run, even if never explicitly called for in Java? Otherwise, I'll keep looking and trying to figure this out. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Component** declared on the class, is going to be read by Spring and it's going to be instantiated as a Spring Bean (by default, is going to be a Singleton, so just one instance) and it's going to be added to the Spring Application Context. Also you can then use the **MySpringClass** all over the application if you **@Autowired** it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html

Comment: So, Spring does the exact opposite of  "lazy class loading"? That is so antithical to Java, I have no words (other than Spring is just weird).

Comment: @feybas Spring has lazy loading but that is not default behavior you as a developer need to switch it on in Spring configuration

Comment: @Ivan is right, you can control the way Spring initializes the objects. By default, all '@Bean', '@Component' and '@Service' annotated classes, will be instantiated at the start of the application and placed in the container. You can configure it to be lazy and the objects will be created only when are needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether your Spring container configured with default lazy initialization of beans (by default is is eager, not lazy).
So by default Spring will create instance of a bean upon creation of Spring context.
And since you are using Spring you do not need to check if code uses constructor directly since Spring will create bean and you **should not** create objects marked as beans using constructor (this eliminates the whole concept of dependency injection and inversion of control).

In case of lazy loading configured Spring will create bean only when it is needed.